# Connecting data to a GUI - OOP

Tags: oop, user-interface, design-patterns

I have an application with several graphs and tables on it.

I worked fast and just made classes like `Graph` and `Table` that each contained a request object (pseudo-code):

```
class Graph {
  private request;

  public function setDateRange(dateRange) {
    request.setDateRange(dateRange);
  }
  public function refresh() {
    request.getData(function() {
      //refresh the display
    });
  }
}
```

Upon a GUI event (say, someone changes the date range dropdown), I'd just call the setters on the `Graph` instance and then refresh it. Well, when I added other GUI elements like tables and whatnot, they all basically had similar methods (`setDateRange` and other things common to the request).

What are some more elegant OOP ways of doing this?

The application is very simple and I don't want to over-architect it, but I also don't want to have a bunch of classes with basically the same methods that are just routing to a request object. I also don't want to set up each GUI class as inheriting from the request class, but I'm open to any ideas really.

Comment: You are saying they basically have similar methods. Are the methods similar or identical? Have you considered using an abstract class that implements the identical methods? Like: AbstractGUIElement

Comment: the methods are identical (they are just calling the method on the request object). even though each gui object has a different instance of the request class, they are serving the same purpose of changing the request objects state.

Comment: sorry i misread your comment. i have considered that but i was avoiding inheritance now because i didnt like the idea of the request object as being part of the gui element, but im actually thinking thats a better idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you commented the methods are identical. In that case I would suggest the following approach.

```
abstract class AbstractGUIElement {

    protected request;

    public function setDateRange(dateRange) {
        request.setDateRange(dateRange);
    }

    abstract function refresh();
}
```

Refreshing would probably be element specific so I have added it as an abstract method the inheriting types have to implement.

```
class Graph extends AbstractGUIElement {

    public function refresh() {
        // Graph specific refreshing
    }
}
```

Comment: over the past 15-30 minutes ive convinced myself using an abstract base class is the best solution. i was initially thinking of not having the gui and request connected like that, but it provides all of the benefits i need and no foreseeable downsides. thanks!